# Limit access to FB application by age

Tags: javascript, facebook, fbml, restriction

I'm looking for a way to limit access to my html FB application to people above age limit (let say 16 years).
I've found forum topic http://forum.developers.facebook.net/viewtopic.php?pid=123010
but there people have problems to achieve this result.

Any one know working way?

Comment: What stops people from lying about their age?

Comment: Online age limits are really more a liability issue than anything else. It's not that people can't lie, it's that you make them lie, then if someone complains about a child using your site you can point to the fact that they SAID they were 18 or 21 or whatever.

Comment: It's kinda like buying a bong at a head shop, everyone knows it's for smoking dope but the store still puts up a sign saying it's only for tobacco.

Comment: It doesn't mater if someone lie or not. Is for legal purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a method we've used:  http://fbdevwiki.com/wiki/Locales#Getting_the_User.27s_Locale

The signed_request has information on country, locale, and age even when the person hasn't logged in.  However, I suspect it's limited to only telling you if a person is over 18, 21, or other key ages.  It may not give the person's specific age.

edit:  The example in the wiki is for the older PHP SDK, I'm not exactly sure how you'd do it in the 3.0 version of the SDK or how it relates to the new OAuth 2.0 change.

Comment: Same here, wondering what the options are , do not know what the various responses for age range would be https://developers.facebook.com/docs/authentication/permissions/